# using partials in Hartl's Rails tutorial, undefined variable method 'object'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through Hartl's Rails tutorial and have been stuck at a rather frustrating point in chapter 10.

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Using this yields this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x00000106cad990>:0x00000103395f18>
```

I have been through it a few times and I am struggling to see where I am going wrong. I've referred to other SO posts but so far none have offered any solution.

Here is

_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li>* <%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

home controller

```
def home
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
  end
```

If i am passing 'object' as the argument through the partial it should work no?

Thanks

Comment: If I remember the Hartl tutorial there are a few places where you may call the _errors partial... in the new template as well as the edit template.  Have you put `object: f.object` in both places?

There's even a point where the tutorial has you move the entire form into a separate partial that (itself) calls the _error partial... if you've reached that point you should check that your _form partial is calling the _error partial with the `object: f.object`

Comment: Can you show me the controller's `#new` action tied to the form you've  listed above?

Comment: @Anthony added the controller

Comment: is a micropost part of another post or does it standalone?

Comment: it belongs to a user, that's all

Comment: ALWAYS POST THE COMPLETE STACKTRACE WHEN ASKING A QUESTION!!! this post might help you figure it out yourself http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/